# Find the Fallacy in the Factor Group Logic

Tags: abstract-algebra, fake-proofs

The factor group for $(\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z})/\langle(2, 0)\rangle$ is clearly $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ because all of the elements are in the form of $a(1, 0)+b(0, 1)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle$ for $a \in \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $b \in \Bbb{Z}$. However, I also have the following argument that it is $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ and I do not know where the mistake is.

$$\tag1 \frac{\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle}{\langle(2, 0)\rangle} \cong \Bbb{Z}$$ because all of the elements are in the form of $z(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle$ for $z \in \Bbb{Z}$.

$$\tag2 \frac{\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}}{\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle}=\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$$

because these are the following elements:

- $\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle$
- $(1, 0)+\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle$
- $(0, 1)+\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle$
- $(1, 1)+\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle$

$$\tag3 \frac{\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}}{\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle} \times \frac{\langle(2, 0), (0, 2)\rangle}{\langle(2, 0)\rangle}=\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$$

However, I am pretty sure this is wrong because it does not make sense. Can someone please explain my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: It's somehow confusing: the group $\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\;$ is very finite (it is Klein's group of order four), so how can a quotient of this group be infinite? Unless you mean something else by $\;\Bbb Z_2\;$ and not the cyclic group of order two. In fact, the element $\;(2,0)=(0,0)\;$ in Klein's group so the quotient is trivial!

Comment: Oops! I wrote $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ when I meant $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$! Thank you so much for catching my mistake.

Comment: And you did it *all the way!* . Please do re-write correctly the question.

Comment: @Joanpemo I was copying and pasting a lot when writing this question...

Comment: @Joanpemo OK, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the following formula:

$$\frac G N*\frac N H \cong \frac G H$$

However, this was your flaw because this is not necessarily true all of the time, as shown by this counter example. In fact, given that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$, it is not even guaranteed $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so given $G/N$ and $N/H$, one can not even deduce $G/H$ exists. However, you can use the Third Isomorphism Theorem, which states the following (given that $N, K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and that $N \subseteq K \subseteq G$):

$$\frac{\frac G N}{\frac K N} \cong \frac G K$$

There is also the Second Isomorphism Theorem, which states the following (given $H, N$ are subgroups of G and $N$ is normal):

$$\frac{HN}{N} \cong \frac{H}{H \cap N}$$

You can use one of these valid rules to help you prove factor groups, but you can not use the invalid rule of just cancelling out groups because it does not always work, as shown by this counterexample.

Also, looks can be deceiving. You have not proven that $(\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z})/\langle(2, 0)\rangle$ simply from your formula. You can also construct a formula such as $a(1, 0)+b(0, 1)+c(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle$ for $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $c \in \Bbb{Z}$. However, it is not actually isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$:

$$((0, 1)+2(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle)+((0, 1)+3(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle)=2(0, 1)+5(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle=6(0, 2)+\langle(2, 0)\rangle$$

Here, $(a_1, b_1, c_1)=(0, 1, 2)$ and $(a_2, b_2, c_2)=(0, 1, 3)$, yet $(a_1, b_1, c_1)+(a_2, b_2, c_2)=(0, 0, 6)$ instead of $(0, 0, 5)$ like in $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}$, so even though it looks isomorphic because of my formula, it is actually not. Your formula is actually isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}$, but just make sure that you prove the isomorphism somehow like [@Joanpemo did using the First Isomorphism Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/309655/joanpemo).

Comment: Your first explanation doesn't hold in this case as all the groups involved are, apparently, abelian. Unless the asker meant something else with his notation.

Comment: Do you mean this sentence: "In fact, given that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$, it is not even guaranteed $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so given $G/N$ and $N/H$, one can not even deduce $G/H$ exists." Otherwise, I do not know what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, exactly that one about normal in normal isn't normal. In this case it clearly is.

Comment: @Joanpemo It is true that this does not really apply to abelian groups, but in general, the first formula I mention at the top is still wrong.

Comment: Perhaps, yet will the apparent mess in the question I cannot even find that easily. The problem seems to be seriously overblown, as a quotient group of a finite group cannot be infinite and thus $\;\Bbb Z\;$ cannot be involved.

Comment: @Joanpemo This was because of a typo in the question. I meant $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$. (Also, I am the same person as the questioner.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that, I believe, will solve the problem and make it swiftly. Define

$$F:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z\;,\;\;f(a,b)=\left(a\pmod2,b\right)$$

Check the above is a surjective group homomorphism and its kernel is

$$(a,b)\in\ker F\iff a\in2\Bbb Z\;\;\wedge\;\;b=0\iff (a,b)\in\langle\,(2,0)\,\rangle$$

Comment: I like this way of solving the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @NobleMushtak A pleasure... after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a "cancellation law":
$$\frac{A}{B}\times \frac{B}{C} = \frac{A}{C}.$$
Over, say, complex numbers (with non-zero denominators) this is fine, but when this is over groups it's nonsense.  There's no way to cancel like this over a direct product of groups (even if we replace the equality with an isomorphism).  In your case you're trying to do this with $A=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, $B=\langle (2,0),(0,2)\rangle$, and $C=\langle 2,0\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is also what [I wrote in my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1717861/307483).